# if $p(\theta|X^n)$ is asymtotic normal, is it still true after applying probability kernel $p(Y|X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reading Clarke and Barron 1990, Information-theoretic asymptotics of Bayes methods

In this paper, the setting is parameter $\theta$ estimation, given $X^n$. There is a kind of regularity condition: page 456, condition 3,

The posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $X^n$ asymptotically concentrates on neighborhoods of $\theta_o$ except for $X^n$ in a set of probability of order $o(1/\log n)$, i.e., for every open set $N$ containing $\theta_0$ and every $\delta > 0$,
$$P^n[W(N^c|X^n) > \delta] = o(1/\log n)$$
where $W(\cdot|X^n)$ is the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $X^n$.

My scenario is "observation for observation", instead of each $X_i$, I observe $Y_i$ through some stochastic kernel $p(y|x)$. So assuming $(\theta ,X)$ satisfies the above concentration, can we still say $(\theta, Y)$ satisfy the above concentration?

edit: Suppose $p(Y|X)$ is nontrivial: let's assume the Fisher information about $I_Y(\theta)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Generally, no, e.g. Y given X could be $\sim U([0,1])$ independent of X. With some conditions, perhaps yes. In the other extreme, $Y = f(X)$ for some one-to-one function, in which case it seems true.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but of course I am not considering such trivial examples..Let me add one more condition, please see the edited version